# Error:(28, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

here is my code of build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shadibazzar.delhibookstore"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile project(":volley")
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

Error:(28, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

- The project 'Delhi Book Store' may be using a version of Gradle that
  does not contain the method.
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: this is your app level gradle can you share your project level gradle file.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i solved it myself :) there was a problem with my project level gradle file.